# how to share ssh keys programmatically on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh

I am often having difficulties to set up password-less ssh connection on my clusters.

So I wrote a script, I thought it was working on ubuntu 14.04. I tried it today on a ubuntu 15 cluster, and it didn't work. 
I am not really sure then if it ever worked on ubuntu 14.4 :-/

It is based on this page : http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

I put the code on this github : https://github.com/romainjouin/formation_spark/blob/master/ubuntu_excange_ssh_keys.sh

the idea is to call the script, passing as first parameter the user@ip where we want to set up a password less ssh connection.

Can someone have a look to the github script : is there an obvious thing I am missing ?

Furthermore, before launching the script I : 
Change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`  to uncomment

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

ant then do :

```
$/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

EDIT

The code seems to work fine, but I was missing the authorisation on the home directory to make it work (home dir was 777 instead of 700).

Comment: you can use `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host` to copy the public key to remote hosts instead of ` cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $1 "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
`

Comment: thanks. I think the issue comes from the agent firing up or not

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please reread  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  . Good luck.

Comment: @shelter : I got your point, but I am a programmer, having to do some infrastructure stuff, so my natural site is stackoverflow... And as I am trying to do "Infrastructure as code", the limit between superuser and developer seems thin to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work fine, but I was missing the authorisation on the home directory to make it work (home dir was 777 instead of 700). – Romain Jouin

Answer (score 0):

suppose you ssh remote-user@remote-host frequently, first

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

then, edit you ~/.ssh/config file

```
cat ~./ssh/config
Host foobar
    HostName remote-host-ip
    Port 22
    User remote-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

now you can ssh like this

```
ssh foobar
```